# How do I assign DateTime field to a variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to assign value of a query to a datetime variable in MySql Stored Procedure.

I'm trying this -

```
DECLARE myDate DATETIME;
    
SET myDate = (SELECT date1 FROM myTable WHERE Id = var_myId);
```

And this

```
DECLARE myDate DATETIME;
    
SELECT date1 into myDate FROM myTable WHERE Id = var_myId;
```

Both don't seem to work as I am not getting the desired result after running the proc.

## EDIT

Problem is in this statement -

```
initial_Date DATETIME; -- param1
interval INTEGER;      -- param2

SET var_date2 = DATE_ADD(initial_Date , INTERVAL interval MINUTE);
```

When I select `var_date2` I get null as result.

Comment: MySQL or SQL server?

Comment: Is `date1` a datetime or some other type? If it's some other type, you'll need to CAST() it to datetime. Also, what results ARE you getting when using either of these methods to set your variable. They are both correctly written.

Comment: MySQL. date1 is a DateTime field in the DB

Comment: Something like this? http://rextester.com/LPQD19388

Comment: Edited problem.

Comment: Use another name for the variable `interval`. Interval is an sql key word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find two issue with your stored procedure.

First, you are naming a variable using an sql key word `interval`. You should rename with an word which is not an sql key word.

The other is you are not setting an out put variable. You can see [the MySQL tutorials on stored procedure.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx)

You can use and try the code below:

```
delimiter //
create procedure test(in initial_time datetime, in minuteInterval integer(2),
                 out final_time datetime)
begin
  set final_time = date_add(initial_time, interval minuteInterval minute);
end//
delimiter ;
```

For testing you can try:

```
call test(now(), 60, @final_time);
select @final_time;
```

Here is the screenshot of my test with **mysql 5.5.21**:
[image: test result]